# Tick control when using PlotLayout

Tags: plotting, ticks, plot-themes

I finally installed 13.3 coming from 12.3 and I was giving some new features a test. I was excited by the new `PlotLayout` feature of `Plot` that generates grids of plots sharing axes. However, I ran into trouble trying to control the appearance of the frame ticks when compared to the standard overlaid presentation:

```
f = Plot[
      {Sin[x], Sin[2 x] - 1/2, Cos[x], Sin[x]^2}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
      Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
      FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Range[-2 Pi, 2 Pi, Pi], None}}
      PlotLayout -> #
    ] &;

f /@ {"Row", Automatic}
```

[image: four plots, with clipped ticks at top and non-symbolic ticks at bottom]
[image: the same four plots, but overlaid in a single panel]

The bottom is what I would have expected: the horizontal frame ticks are symbolic multiples of $\pi$, and no ticks are produced at the bottom and on the right of the plot.

The top figure, stemming from the "Row" arrangement, was surprising to me: I didn't get the symbolic ticks at the bottom, there are unexpected ticks at the top that are partially clipped, there are clipped ticks on the right as well... In short, a rather poor presentation.

- How do I get symbolic ticks in a multipanel plot?
- How do I achieve control of which ticks are shown on which axes?
- I understand the choice of making all plots the same color in the Row presentation but, if needed, could I have the grid of plots automatically styled in the default colors, as used in the standard overlaid presentation?

Comment: From what I can tell, the `PlotLayout` functionality offers very limited (if any) per-panel control over the various settings (although this is rather a case of not even a common setting working). If you really want the extra level of control, I'd suggest you to take a look at [`ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid/) - while less automatic, you can simply style each panel as you want before combining them (with many options for fine-tuning the result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Lukas Lang noted in comments [ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid/) is a much more convenient alternative to `PlotLayout`.

A work-around to get the desired results using `PlotLayout`:

1. Wrap input functions with desired styles using `Style`.
2. Specify ticks as a list of  $\{value, label\}$ pairs.
3. Use `FrameTicksStyle` to make unwanted ticks invisible.

```
funcs = {Sin[x], Sin[2 x] - 1/2, Cos[x], Sin[x]^2};

colors = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[Range[Length @ funcs]];

styledfuncs = MapThread[Style] @ {funcs, colors};

ft = {{Automatic, None},
  {Transpose[{#, ToString[#, TraditionalForm] & /@ #}] & @ 
   Range[-2 π, 2 π, π], None}};


f2 = Plot[Evaluate @ styledfuncs,
    {x, -2 π, 2 π},
    ##2,
    PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
    Axes -> False,
    Frame -> True,
    FrameTicks -> ft,
    FrameTicksStyle -> {{Automatic, Opacity[0]}, {Automatic, Opacity[0]}},
    PlotLayout -> #] &;

Grid[List /@ 
  {f2["Row", ImageSize -> 1 -> 70, Method -> {"Spacings" -> {16, 1}}],
   f2[Automatic, ImageSize -> 1 -> 60]}]
```

[image]

```
Grid[List @ 
   {f2["Column", ImageSize -> 1 -> 70,
      PlotLegends -> None, Method -> {"Spacings" -> {5, 5}}],
    f2[Automatic, ImageSize -> 1 -> 60]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent as usual. Thank you!